# How to calculate the limit of the following function?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

How can I calculate the limit of the following function?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-|x+y|}{e^{x^2}{^{+2xy+y^2}}}$$

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

the exponential function is continuos so you can pull the limit inside and thus get $$\exp\left({\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{-|x+y|}{|x+y|^2}}\right) .$$
I presume you can go on from here by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ and $a^2=|a|^2$.